# Half-wavelengths of the electric field fit in the cavity length $L$: $m \frac{\lambda}{2n} = L$

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, photonics, laser-cavity

I am currently studying *Laser Systems Engineering* by Keith Kasunic. Chapter **1.2.1 Temporal Coherence** says the following:

> Axial (or longitudinal) modes are determined by the geometrical fit (or *resonance*) of a given wavelength in the laser cavity. That is, if the two mirrors that define a laser cavity are nearly planar and perfectly reflecting – an ideal assumption, given that one mirror will be designed *not* to be so that light can escape the cavity as output power – then Fig. 1.12 shows that an integer number $m = 1, 2, 3$, etc., of half-wavelengths of the electric field fit in the cavity length $L$:
> $$m \dfrac{\lambda}{2n} = L \ \ \ \ \ \text{[m]} \tag{1.4}$$
> where the refractive index $n$ of the gain medium is included to account for the reduction in wavelength in comparison with its free-space ($n = 1$) value. With the exception of a specific type of semiconductor laser known as a vertical-cavity surface-emitting laser (VCSEL) with a cavity length $L \approx \lambda$, the number of half-wavelengths is large in practice. For example, for a HeNe laser emitting at $\lambda = 633$ nm with $L = 100$ mm and $n \approx 1$, $m = 2L/\lambda = 2 \times 0.1 \ \text{m} / 633 \ \text{nm} = 315,955$ half-wavelengths.
> [image]

I understand the cavity length $m \dfrac{\lambda}{2n} = L$, as a standalone, but what is meant by "half-wavelengths" of the *electric field*, and how is this represented mathematically, in terms of electromagnetism and electromagnetic waves? And, relatedly, how does the $m$ values, as shown in figure 1.12, influence the electromagnetic waves themselves, beyond the simple equation of the cavity length $m \dfrac{\lambda}{2n} = L$ (that is, where in the mathematics of electromagnetic waves does the $m \dfrac{\lambda}{2n} = L$ come into play)?

Comment: It's very simple, a *half-wavelength* is a distance equal to half the wavelength. If the wavelength is 632 nm, then a half-wavelength is 316 nm.

Comment: @ThePhoton But that doesn't answer my questions with regards to the context of electromagnetic waves. I'm looking for more detail within that context.

Comment: There's nothing special about EM waves in explaining this term. If 1 meter is 100 cm, then a half meter is 50 cm. If one wavelength is 632 nm, then a half wavelength is 316 nm. It's represented mathematically by $\lambda/2$, just like you used it in your post.

Comment: @ThePhoton Then why do they mention "half-wavelengths of the *electric field*"?

Comment: @ThePhoton Furthermore, how do the different values of $m$, as shown in the figure, give rise to those different waves? $m \dfrac{\lambda}{2n} = L$ doesn't seem to explain that.

Comment: They're being over-specific. The wavelength would be the same if you measured the magnetic field. The diagram shows a case where 6 wavelengths (i.e. 12 half-wavelengths) fit in the cavity (labeled m=12) and a case where 5 wavelengths (10 half-wavelengths) fit labeled m=10, and a case where 4 wavelengths (8 half-wavelengths) fit, labeled m=8. In each case the number *m* is equal to the number of half-wavelengths in the cavity.

Comment: Presumably *n* is the index of refraction of the material in the cavity and $\lambda$ is the vacuum wavelength, so that the actual wavelength in the material is $\lambda/n$.

Comment: @ThePhoton Oh wow, you're right; I completely missed that. Ok, I think this clarifies things. You can post all of this as an answer if you like, so that I can close this question.

Answer (score 1):

the cavity length must be a multiple of the half wavelength of the laser (and the laser is a wave in the electric field). That's the 2 in the divisor of the formula.
The "m" tells you that in a given cavity length several frequencies can resonate, so for example, if 100Ghz can resonate, then so do 200,300,400GHz etc...

BTW that drawing is misleading, I believe a standing wave must have a potential of 0 at the wall of the cavity, that's related to the fact that only an integer number of half wavelength of a radiation can resonate.